# rsync: Remember copied files, even if they are deleted at the destination

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, synchronization

I want to run an rsync job that copies data from A to B.
The data at the destination will be deleted after processing.
However, the processed data should no longer be copied.
Is there a way that rsync remembers the deleted data on the target and only copies the new data in the source?
Maybe there is a way to make a ongoing list and exclude the data from the list?

Comment: Move the source files to another directory.

Answer (score 3):

Two different approaches are possible:

- make a selection of the files that need transferring and feed that list to rsync and only those files will be copied. The `find` command is particularly useful for that.
  For example use `find -ctime 1 -print0 /path/  | rsync --files-from -`
  But other sources, filename patterns, a database query,  input from the application that creates the files etc. etc. are also good candidates to select specific files to copy.
- rsync can maintain a log with the actions it performed. (Check `man rsync` and look for the `--log-file=FILE` and `--log-file-format=FMT` options).  After a successful batch, append the file/path names from that log to the list of previously copied files.  Then use that concatenated list as the `--exclude-from=FILE` in the next rsync run to prevent those files from getting copied again.

Note that neither approach is immediately 100% fool proof and you need to carefully consider the implications of edge cases, files that don't get copied, files that copied a second time and what happens when state/history is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled into this question while searching for a solution to a similar use case.

I wrote a script (I'm not a bash expert, so use with caution) that solves sync of two directories and keeps the history. It's a one way sync and files from source directory will never be synced to destination directory after the first time they are transferred.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Sync two directories with rsync, but keep history to optimize the process.
# On subsequent runs it will only sync files added since last sync.
#
# Accepts two arguments source and destination directory.
# Make sure source and destination do not end with a slash.
# Script assumes that both source and destination directory already exist. It
# is meant only to sync source content to destination content.
#
# When started it will output where it saves history. Do not delete that file!
# Delete history file if you want to re-sync from clean state.
#
# Example usage
# In parent directory of Audiobooks run:
# ./sync_with_history.sh Audiobooks user@xhostname:/media/ServerMedia/Audiobooks
# to sync files to a remote server. You'll need ssh access set up.
#
# To sync local directories simply run:
# ./sync_with_history.sh Audiobooks /path/to/destination/Audiobooks
# in the parent directory of Audiobooks.

# Create history file name
escaped1=$(echo $1 | tr / -)
escaped2=$(echo $2 | tr / -)
sync_with_history_done_list="sync_with_history_done_list-$escaped1-to-$escaped2"
echo "Saving history to $sync_with_history_done_list"
# Ensure sync_with_history_done_list exists
touch $sync_with_history_done_list

# List all not rsync-ed files to a list
find $1 -mindepth 1 -type f -printf '%P\n' | grep -vFf $sync_with_history_done_list > sync_with_history_todo_list
cat sync_with_history_todo_list | while read line
do
    echo "Sending: $line"
        echo "$line" > files-to-include
        # NOTE: use rsync -a if you want to keep permissions, owner, group etc.
        # I use -r because I don't need those.
        rsync -r --files-from=files-to-include $1/ $2/
        echo "$line" >> $sync_with_history_done_list
done

# Clean up. leave only sync_with_history_done_list
touch files-to-include
rm files-to-include
rm sync_with_history_todo_list
```

You can find the script on Github: https://gist.github.com/Spoygg/f6cdfbe6627a41fcf75fa7320b9dee3d
with more details I left out here.